# What's the difference between 図る、測る、計る、量る、諮る、謀る?

Tags: word-choice, usage, homophonic-kanji

These six words are all pronounced はかる, and many are listed under the same definitions in dictionaries.

What are the difference between these words?

Comment: Oooh, did a post on this at renshuu.org a few months back.  I'll go ahead and bring it over.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [http://dict.hjenglish.com/jp/jc/はかる](http://dict.hjenglish.com/jp/jc/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B)

### 計る - to measure (quantities and in general)

> “計る”指计数物品的数量。转义为计划。如“计划时间”、“量体温”、“计算数量”、“筹划组织的将来”等。
>   （「計る」は、物の数を数えること。転じて、計画すること。「時間を計る」「体温を計る」「数量を計る」「組織の将来を計る」など。）

計る is used for counting/measuring the number of something. It can also mean "to plan". (General word for measuring things)

- 時間を計る - Plan a time
- 体温を計る - Measure body temperature
- 数量を計る - Count the quantity
- 組織の将来を計る - Plan the organisation's future

### 量る - to measure (a three dimensional amount)

> “量る”指确定重量及体积。如“称重量”、“量体重”、“测量容积”、“称分量”等。
>   （「量る」は、重さやかさを調べること。「目方（めかた）を量る」「体重を量る」「容積を量る」「分量を量る」など。）

量る is used to measure weight and volume.

- 目方を量る - Measure weight
- 体重を量る - Measure body weight
- 容積を量る - Measure volume/capacity
- 分量を量る - Measure an amount/quantity

### 測る - to measure (lengths and areas)

> “測る”指测定长度及高度等。如“测量距离”、“测标高”、“测水深”、“测量面积”等。
>   （「測る」は、長さや高さなどを調べること。「距離を測る」「標高を測る」「水深を測る」「面積を測る」など。）

測る is used to measure length, height, etc.

- 距離を測る - Measure distance
- 標高を測る - Measure elevation/altitude
- 水深を測る - Measure depth of water
- 面積を測る - Measure area

### 図る - to plan

> “図る”指对事物作出估计。如“谋求问题的解决”、“谋求经营的合理化”、“谋求促进”等。
>   （「図る」は、物事の見積（みつ）もりをたてること。「問題の解決図る」「経営の合理化を図る」「促進を図る」など。）

図る is used to plan or aim towards things.

- 問題の解決図る - Seek the problem's resolution
- 経営の合理化を図る - Attempt to streamline running the business
- 促進を図る - Attempt to promote (an idea)

### 謀る - to plot

> “謀る”指计划不好的事情。如“图谋暗杀”、“企图秘密入境”、“被巧妙地骗了”等。
>   （「謀る」は、よくないことを計画すること。「暗殺を謀る」「密入国を謀る」「まんまと謀られた」など。）

謀る is used to plot or aim towards bad things. (Same as 図る but for bad things)

- 暗殺を謀る - Plot an assassination
- 密入国を謀る - Plot to illegally immigrate
- まんまと謀られた - I was skillfully deceived

### 諮る - to discuss

> “諮る”指与人交换意见。如“向审议会征求意见”、“与委员会磋商”等。
>   （「諮る」は、人と意見を出し合うこと。「審議会に諮る」「委員会に諮る」など。）

諮る is used to indicate the exchange of opinions.

- 審議会に諮る - Petition the working group
- 委員会に諮る - Negotiate with the commitee

Answer (score 4):

*Information comes from the disambiguation notes in 大辞林 for はかる.*

### はかる

General meaning: To plan out; to measure

### 計る

measure, take; weigh; sound; time; gauge

*Use 計る when examining the time or extent of something*

### 諮る

consult (with); submit

*諮る means “to get the opinion of another person” or “to consult for advice”.*

### 図る

plan; conspire, plot; try, attempt; seek; aim for; work for

*図る means “to form a plan, with the intent to make it real.”  If it’s something you’re setting a goal to do [e.g. 目指す], then use 図る*

### 測る

*測る means “to measure length and/or breadth.”*

### 謀る

*謀る means “to deceive”.*

Similar to 図る above, 謀る also means to consider from a variety of angles, take measurements, and execute a plan so that an existing objective can become a reality.

*If you’re planning something evil, 謀る is commonly used for this purpose*

### 量る

*量る means “to measure weight or capacity” or “to estimate”.*